# Is it WCAG Compatible to highlight a row for a quick moment?

Tags: accessibility, wcag2.0

so I tried looking through the documentation, but I don't seem to find a real answer for that. I've got a button which when clicked directs the user to a specific table row, whose background then is highlighted for like 3 seconds in a color. Question is: is that okay for WCGA? I mean its a time limited event and the user can't deactivate that, but is the change of a background for a few seconds counted as time limited event? And is it a problem that this only happens visually?

Comment: Would you like an answer solely based on the legislation, i.e. the WCAG, or based on what would be useful to the concerned users? (:

Comment: Are you showing a toast or another status message indicating successful addition of the row?

Comment: @Andy Based on the Legislation :) And I'm not showing any toast, it just takes them straight to the page where the row's bg then is shorty highlighted until it fades back to white. Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button is setting focus to that row as well, there should be no issue at all.

For example, from [Understanding Success Criterion 4.1.3: Status Messages](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/status-messages.html)

> make users aware of important changes in content that are not given focus

As [focus must be visible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-visible), users have all the time in the world to analyse the newly focussed row, so you will not fail Guideline 2.2: Enough Time.

What becomes tricky in your case are the contrasts between the animated background colour and the [focus indicator, which will need to be at least 3:1 as of WCAG 2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/#focus-appearance-minimum).

That is if you don’t use the focus style itself for the highlight (:

Comment: Thanks for that info! Currently I am not setting focus to the row, but then I'll add that as well and make sure the contrast will be enough